# How do I modify permissions to a shared folder with java?

Tags: java, permissions, directory, shared

I have the following problem:

I have a shared folder on my computer(Windows OS). I need a script in Java that when runned blocks the acces of network users to this folder so that I am allowed to modify its content.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Java 7 or later, you could use the [`java.nio.Files.setAttribute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#setAttribute%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29) to set the DOS permissions using the relevant attributes from the `DosFileAttributeView`.

(You might also be able to do it using `AclFileAttribute` or `PosixFileAttribute` ... depending on the true nature of the folder you are attempting to modify.)

For Java 6 or earlier, you would need to resort to a 3rd-party library, JNI/JNA calls, or using `Process` to run an external command.